# Bochs TUN/TAP setup

Tags: linux, emulation

I'm trying to set up a network with Bochs using TUN/TAP within Win98 on a Linux machine.

Here are some of my settings (in Windows 98):

`IP Address`
`Specify IP address`

`IP Address: 192.168.1.2`
`Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0`

`DNS Configuration`
`Host: catch22bbs Domain: com`

`DNS Server Search Order`
`192.168.1.10`

`Installed gateways`
`192.168.1.10`

Here is my `bochsrc.txt`

```
megs: 724
cpu: count=1, ips=25000000, reset_on_triple_fault=1, ignore_bad_msrs=1
# filename of ROM images
romimage: file=BIOS-bochs-latest
vgaromimage: file=VGABIOS-lgpl-latest
vga: extension=cirrus, update_freq=25
pci: enabled=1, chipset=i440fx, slot1=cirrus
ata0: enabled=1, ioaddr1=0x1f0, ioaddr2=0x3f0, irq=14
ata0-master: type=disk, path="win98.img"
journal=vvfat.redolog
ata1-master: type=cdrom, path="win98.iso", status=inserted
boot: disk
config_interface: textconfig
#display_library: x
# other choices: win32 sdl wx carbon amigaos beos macintosh nogui rfb term        svga
log: bochsout.txt 
sb16: enabled=1
mouse: enabled=1
sb16: wavemode=1, dmatimer=500000
clock: sync=none, time0=1
ne2k: ioaddr=0x300, irq=3, mac=fe:fd:00:00:00:01, ethmod=tuntap, ethdev=/dev/net/tun, script=/root/Downloads/ANDROID/bochs/img/tunconfig
```

Here is my `tunconfig` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/ifconfig ${1##/*/} 192.168.1.0

/sbin/iptables -D POSTROUTING -t nat -s 192.168.1.0  -d ! 192.168.1.0  -j MASQUERADE >& /dev/null
/sbin/iptables -t nat -s 192.168.1.0  -d ! 192.168.1.0  -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

ifconfig tun 192.168.1.0 up

route del -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev tun
route add -net 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev tun

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun/proxy_arp
arp -Ds 192.168.1.0 tun pub
```

I'm not sure if it matters or not, but my actual IP (on the Linux side) is
`192.168.1.10`

So, my question is: do I have it set up correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: If my configuration is correct or not. Sorry. Should of made that clear.